# How to encrypt the sqlite file in IOS and which one is good method?

Tags: iphone

Hi I would like to encrypt my database(sqlite) file and which encryption method is good for IOS development. Thank's in advance.

Comment: No effort or attempt shown.

Comment: Not like that i saw few (sqlchiper) but i could not get, so i am waiting for some other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) fencrypt my database(sqlite) file.It's a build of SQLite that provides transparent, page-level encryption of the entire DB. There's a tutorial over on [Mobile Orchard](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/) for using it in iPhone apps.